# Access a text file in GCS from Informatica IICS with a parameter source object

Tags: google-cloud-storage, informatica, informatica-cloud, iics, iics-di

I am using IICS to run a taskflow containing two mapping tasks.

The data source is set as a parameter and is assigned in an assignment inside the taskflow. In the assignment I set the source of both mapping tasks equal to an input parameter created in the Start object.

I then attempt to test using the taskflow "Run Using" option. The taskflow errors stating that `"Operation failed: Object(s) [abc.txt] not found"`.

I am trying to figure out why the process can't see the file. Inside of the mapping tasks when I set up the source I am able to select it without issue.

Comment: Where is the file located? Have you provided full path from the server perspective?

Comment: It is located in a bucket inside GCS. When I use "Run Using" I have the parameter with the full location (minus gs://) and file name

Comment: It seems to me that it can not be reached by Secure Agent. Try placing the file locally in infashared folder and give it a go. Next steps would depend on the results of the test.

Comment: Provide full path. In case of isseus, test the path if it's reachable from server perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by hard coding the directory in the advanced section in the mapping task in the source section. This includes the gs://